# Why Does An Image That Scales Up Overflow Past max-height?

Tags: html, css

**EDIT #1**

This seems to be an issue with the size of the image and how it scales up or down. Also, this behavior is coupled closely with the image being square; the width and height being equated/interchanged.

When the inherent dimensions of the image are smaller than the `min-height`, the image container will only accommodate a `min-height`s worth of width for the image, forcing it to overflow. Once the inherent image dimensions become larger than the `max-height`, the image container expands to fit the image.

Bonus conundrum: When put into a vertical flexbox, the ***copy container*** overflows instead of the image container. (click on boxes in snippet to switch) [Here's the same example in Codepen](https://codepen.io/varystrategic/pen/WNMwodr)

```js
document.querySelector('main').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    this.classList.toggle('col');
}, true);
```

```css
main {
    display: flex;
}
main.col {
  flex-direction: column;
}

section {
    display: flex;
    margin: 2rem;
    background: rgba(0,255,255); // cyan
}

.icon {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

img {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 1rem;
    max-height: 4rem;
    width: auto;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.copy {
    background: rgba(255,255,0,0.5);
}


html,
body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main class="col">
    <section>
        <div class="icon">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/1/1"/>
        </div>
        <div class="copy">
            blah<br>
            blah<br>
            blah<br>
            blah<br>
            blah
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div class="icon">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/40/40"/>
        </div>
        <div class="copy">
            blah<br>
            blah<br>
            blah<br>
            blah<br>
            blah
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div class="icon">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/80/80"/>
        </div>
        <div class="copy">
            blah<br>
            blah<br>
            blah<br>
            blah<br>
            blah
        </div>
    </section>
</main>
```

---

**ORIGINAL**

I have a flexbox with an image on the left and copy on the right. I want the image to maintain aspect ratio based on height (thus using `width: auto`). I also want to limit the height of the image, both min and max. But, if the copy side gets taller than the max-height of the image, the "auto width" of the image is ignored and overflows its container. Why doesn't the left side of the flex expand width to contain the image?

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  background: rgba(0,255,255);
}

.image {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 3rem;
  max-height: 4rem;
  width: auto;
  background: rgba(255,0,255,0.5);
}

.copy {
  background: rgba(255,255,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/1x1.png"/>
  </div>
  <div class="copy">
    blah<br>
    blah<br>
    blah<br>
    blah<br>
    blah
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: I have no overflow with an actually working image.

Comment: width:auto is already the default value and will do nothing

Comment: @tacoshy is kinda correct. It seems the (ie, "actually working") image needs to be at least the size of the max-height declaration to not overflow; it needs to scale down, not up. I still would love to know the answer / why this happens, but at least I'm unblocked.

Comment: Actually, I'm still blocked. With the original size of the image being larger than the max-height, it never "shrinks" to the min-height when the copy on the right shrinks. #backtothedrawingboard